# H:CommandLink actionListener code fires again when a jsf component is clicked

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, popupwindow, commandlink

I have a JSP page containing a `h:dataTable`. The datatable has a column of `h:commandLink` components which open a new popup window. These commandLink components have an `actionListener` method in the page's backing bean. The code determines which commandLink component was clicked, grabs its parameter and redirects to a servlet. The servlet writes a file to the popup window and displays the "save as/open" dialog box so user's can download the file written. This all works fine.

However, after closing the popup window, if I click on a JSF button on the page, I get the "save as/open" dialog box again.  How do I prevent this dialog box from reappearing? I noticed this doesn't happen if `Page1.jsp` is refreshed before the JSF button is clicked.

Here is the code:

`Page1.jsp`

```
<noscript>
<!-- Page1.jsp -->
    <webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{Page1.btnSubmit_action}" id="btnSubmit" text="Apply"/>

<h:column id="column9">
  <h:commandLink  value=" Open " target="popupWindow" actionListener="#{Page1.openPopupClicked}" >
<f:param id="tmpFileId" name="id" value="#{currentRow['J_LINK']}" />
</h:commandLink>
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="#{currentRow['J_LINK']}"/>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText id="outputText18" value="More "/>
</f:facet>
</h:column>
</noscript>
```

`Page1` backing bean

```
public void openPopupClicked(ActionEvent event){
      UIParameter tmpFileName = (UIParameter)event.getComponent().findComponent("tmpFileId");
      if(tmpFileName==null)
        return;
      String fName = (String)tmpFileName.getValue();
      if(fName==null)
        return;
      final String viewId = "/FileDisplayerServlet";
      HttpSession hs = this.getHttpSession();
      hs.setAttribute("tmpToShow", fName);
      this.redirectToServlet(viewId);     
   }
```

Servlet code called by processRequest method:

```
private void printFileToScreen(HttpServletRequest request,String tmpFileToShow, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException{
      ServletOutputStream sos = null;
      FileInputStream in = null;
       try{
          response.reset();
          response.setContentType(getContentType(tmpFileToShow));

          if(currFileExt==null)
            return;
          String fileName = "document.".concat(currFileExt);
          sos = response.getOutputStream();
          response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; fileName="+fileName);
          File src = new File(tmpFileToShow);
          in = new FileInputStream(src);
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len =0;

          response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
          while((len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0){
            sos.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
        }catch(IOException ie){
          System.out.println("printFileToScr: "+ie.toString());
        }finally{
          if(sos!=null)
            {sos.flush(); sos.close();}
          if(in!=null)
          {in.close();}


        }
  }
```

Comment: `webuijsf` .. That's the Woodstock library which was abandoned around end of 2005 and isn't been supported/developed anymore since then. It had too much JS bugs of which a major part exposed in "the better" browsers like Firefox/Chrome. Some core parts of its JS didn't follow the ECMA standard and were too MSIE specific. I'm sorry, I don't know an answer to this, just wanted to inform you that Woodstock is dead for ages. Best what I can say is: "try upgrading/replacing JSF impl and library".

Comment: I think I will change it later on. But I found a little work around. I created a flag (an int) that is updated when the jsf button is clicked. When the openPopupClicked method is launch, I check the flag. If it is set, I clear it and do not proceed with the popup action. But I can assure you that I'll be upgrading.